# How to place cross references in center margin between two columns

Tags: cross-referencing, positioning, margins, columns, paracol

How can I put all cross references in the center margin, with those for the left column vertically positioned above those for the right column?  The text will wrap to additional pages, and the cross references will need to follow the text.

I've seen a way to create three columns such as with `\usepackage{multicol}` and `\begin{multicols}{3}`, but I have yet to find any documentation for putting a "functional" margin space between *two* columns where marginal notes could be placed.

Note: If it isn't possible, I would rather be told so directly--in which case I may need to find another software.  This is a feature I would see as a deal breaker for me.

Per request (see below), here's a [link to an online image](http://localchurchbiblepublishers.com/wp-content/uploads/120-MidSizeWMClassicOpen.jpg) that I found via google of a page exemplifying the type of center margin layout which I require.  (The forum does not permit the use of [table tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), and I don't know how, or don't have sufficient privilege, to upload an image here.)

26 Nov. '19 Update: Believe it or not, I am *still* looking for a solution to this.  It is my hope that in the past 4-5 years something may have developed that would make this possible.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you mean?  I'm not sure `multicolumn` is the way to go.

Comment: I would have been happy to demonstrate here what I mean, but I need to create a table to do it, and it's not allowed here.  I don't know how to upload a picture.  Basically, I want two columns, and cross references for both of them to be noted between them in a center margin (no references on left/right margins).  The references should appear in the same order as the text, with those for the left column at the top of the margin, followed by those for the right column further down.  Where the text in the columns wraps to the next page, the references should also wrap correspondingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but an image would be really useful. I don't understand why creating a table is 'not allowed here', and I believe adding an image is pretty easy: there's a button on the editing toolbar, even. (It should be simple to [find out how to upload images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491).)

Comment: @jon I just updated my question to add a link for you.  I also gave a link to why HTML table tags are not allowed--which I also do not understand.

Comment: I think you need to make an ASCII representation of a table using Markdown syntax. Note that this site does not mainly rely on HTML for its input. But how much 'rep' do you need to upload images? I thought it was 15 (but I clearly don't remember). The link is useful though. Looks like a nightmare to implement so the text flows automatically from column to column.

Comment: I am not aware an out-of-the-box solution. Possibly something can be hacked up by using the code for the `marginnote` package. One would have to have a way, however, of "sorting" the cross references between the left and right columns, this should be possible because `marginnote`, for example, already use `\pdfsavepos` etc to store the vertical positions, and readjust them as necessary when printing the notes.